# Using Selenium to 'click' on non-input or non-control elements

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

Has anyone been successful with getting Selenium to issue a mouse click on an element which is not associated with input, i.e. **plain text**?  I have tried using click() and click_at() methods, as well as fire_event(locator, event), where 'event' is 'onclick', or by using combination of 'onmousedown' and 'onmouseup' events.  I have also tried preceding these events with an 'onmouseover' event.  In my app, clicking on this 'plain text' triggers a call to a flash.swf routine.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a part of html on which you are trying clicking?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adapting a Mouse Listener? In case you are extending Selenium using Java, [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) is a quick tutorial.

Comment: This will not work in this case - Mouse Listeners are for AWT/Swing applications

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried fire_event(locator, 'click') instead of 'onclick'?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried tweaking fire event? As you are mentioning it as plain text locator of this should be like `//p[contains(text(),'yourtext')]` something like this. Try it once.

Answer (score 0):

A native `.click()` event should work fine if your using `Firefox 31.6.0 ESR` (not a later version),  or if your using Chrome.   Keep in mind that for any event where a physical mouse click is not working for you (for whatever reason), you can still call a JavascriptExecutor to click the element (which is referred to as a synthetic non-native Selenium event).