# Selenium.click not working on some anchor elements

Tags: jquery, selenium, fullcalendar, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

The application that am working on was recently revamped and as part of that a new JQuery calendar was introduced. I need to click on a link in the calendar to select the time and date. However, Selenium.click is not working. The command gets executed, but nothing happens on the screen.

To check whether my XPATH/CSS locator (I tried both) is correct, I added selenium.getText(locator) and selenium.highlight(locator) commands. Both worked!. No issues in that. Its ONLY the click that is not working.

Upon checking in firebug, I could see that the div on which I am trying to click is kind of grayed out state. Does it meant that element is disabled? See the screenshot of the firebug below.

I also tried to run the same command in Selenium IDE. In IDE this works "sometimes".

I am running this test using Selenium 1.xx.

**UPDATE:**

> I did one more thing as part of
>   debugging. During the test run, I
>   opened the Selenium IDE in the browser
>   so that it records what actions are
>   happening. IDE recorded all actions
>   till this click. But I couldn't see
>   anything in the IDE when the click
>   command was executed. Any idea guys,
>   what would be cause?

Has anyone faced a similar issue before? Any help would be appreciated!!![image: Firebug screenshot]

Comment: Are you using selenium 1 or 2?

Comment: Greyed out does mean disabled, but I suspect it will enable when you mouse over something.  Is there a publically visible page with this calendar control on that we can look at?

Comment: Unfortunately no, its not a public site.

Answer (score 2):

Try `selenium.fireEvent(locater, 'click')`, or using Selenium 2 which is more tightly integrated with the browser.

You may be having the same problem as some other people, eg.

[Selenium clicks not working with GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185047/selenium-clicks-not-working-with-gwt)

[Using Selenium to 'click' on non-input or non-control elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045006/using-selenium-to-click-on-non-input-or-non-control-elements)

It seems to be related to click events which are added with Javascript.

**Edited**

I don't know if you're using the same calendar implementation, but I discovered that the fullcalendar.js jQuery one replaces the mouseover event, and you have to trigger that first. I got it to work using

```
selenium.runScript("jQuery(\"a:contains('" + NEW_EVENT_NAME
        + "')\").trigger('mouseover');jQuery(\"a:contains('"
        + NEW_EVENT_NAME + "')\").trigger('click')");
```

Comment: selenium.fireEvent did not work. Unfortunately I can't move to Selenium 2 now. The other issues which you have given solved the issue using Selenium 2.

Comment: Awarding the bounty to this as this is the closest answer I could get. Hopefully this issue will be resolved by Selenium 2.0. Now that Grid 2.0 is out, I can try this. Thankyou

Comment: Sorry you couldn't resolve the issue completely, if it's any consolation there are some click events which I've never managed to fire either :-(

Comment: might be worth trying my updated answer (my previous comment had a typo, mouseOver instead of mouseover)...

Comment: Thanks artbristol :), I will try it.

Comment: mouse over and then click! That worked for me. I ran in to this with trying to click spans in an ember-based app that apparently was doing something similar. Thanks @artbristol !

Comment: I got it working like this: runScript("jQuery(\"div.fc-event-time:contains('" + EVENT_NAME + "')\").trigger('mouseover').trigger('click');");

Answer (score 0):

Our JQuery calendar implementation is compatible with the default Selenium locators, even though the locators appear disabled in the DOM. Here's an example, for you to try:

```
selenium.click("link=11:00 AM - 01:00 PM");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just assume your XPATH to get that span is correct, I suspect your selenium script is running faster than your page load, so add this function to wait until the page is loaded

```
waitForPageToLoad
```

Hope helps
:)

Comment: Would have been really easy if that was the case :). It doesn't cause a page load

Comment: And to make sure wait was not the issue, I did debug the code using breakpoints. No luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
selenium.focus("locator path of where you want to click");
selenium.keyPressNative("10"); // this is clicking entering button
```

this should do the job.

Make sure that you don't touch the mouse while Selenium is executing your `keyPressNative` statement.

Comment: Shouldn't the same work manually? Like if i hover the mouse or use tab to reach the element and then press enter?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across with the similar problem recently. Please note, I work with Selenium driver. So I'm not sure whether my approach is suitable for Selenium 1.xx

The problem was in clicking invisible menu elemnt , which appears on mouse hover event.
The solution I found for Firefox selenium driver:

```
WebElement mnuElement;
WebElement submnuElement;
mnEle = driver.findElement(By.Id("mnEle")).Click();
sbEle = driver.findElement(By.Id("sbEle")).Click();

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
// Move cursor to the Main Menu Element
builder.MoveToElement(mnEle).Perform();
// Giving 5 Secs for submenu to be displayed
Thread.sleep(5000L);
// Clicking on the Hidden SubMenu
driver.findElement(By.Id("sbEle")).Click();
```

Here's the [link](http://www.anitpatel.net/2012/02/25/selenium-webdriver-how-to-click-on-a-hidden-link-or-menu/)

Main idea is to create instance of Actions and try to focus on your element and click it.
I would act in the following way:
//find xpath of your invisible element:

```
    String xpathInvisible = "//*[id="calendar"]/div/div/div/div[1]";

//find xpath of the element, on hovering which your invisible (inactive) element appear. I mean somthing //like VDIs (see my screen) on pressing which menu elements appear.

    String xpathCalendarToAppear =".....";

WebElement calendarToAppear= driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathCalendarToAppear));
WebElement invisibleElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathInvisible));

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.MoveToElement(calendarToAppear).Perform();
// Giving 5 Secs for submenu to be displayed
Thread.sleep(5000L);
// Clicking on the Hidden SubMenu
invisibleElement.Click();
```

In firefox this works OK. But IE driver has problems with clicking on elements.
So I overcome this "IE problem" using jscript directly in the following way:

```
WebElement hiddenWebElement =driver.findElement(By.xpath(....));
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()",hiddenWebElement);
```

we initialize hiddenWebElement variable with element  we want to click on.
And using jscript we click on it.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem to yours (one anchor/link element out a hundred or so I'd tested before just fine refused to be clicked by a standard selenium click method).

In my case, I was able to solve the problem, for reasons entirely unclear to me, using Selenium WebDriver Actions (documented [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) for Java and [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/b/bbc-selenium-webdriver-1.17.0/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html) for Ruby) to execute a clickAndHold/click_and_hold action followed by a release action. In Ruby, this is done like so (code example from Ruby documentation of release):

```
el = driver.find_element(:id, "some_id")
driver.action.click_and_hold(el).release.perform
```

Hoping this helps someone else, and perhaps that someone with more insight can explain the reasons behind this.