# Replace tool for Selenium for testing Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, selenium

I have problem with Selenium tool to testing the web application which contains some of jQuery. (Some problem based on javascript event such [onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134708/selenium-click-not-working-on-some-anchor-elements) issue, [onchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544336/selenium-onchange-not-working) issue). Sometime, fireEvent() cannot help to show correct behaviour.

Such as I use [jquery.facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/) plugin (plugin such blockUI), in case that I click, it should show fade in, but it wasn't, and it try to open new page with content inside facebox instead.

Are there any other free software which we can use to make function test such selenium? or any selenium plugin that help to solve the problem with javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You can look at Phantomjs. It à headless driver for Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Never used it but I heard that [Telerik's Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/) is a good Selenium alternative

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are looking for an alternative so with that in mind WatiN is a common choice, though it only works well (IMO the firefox support is not great) in IE and you are likely to hit the same roadblocks.

However, it sounds to me that you are (potentially) not interacting with the UI correctly. You might benefit more from trying to call the javascript through Selenium WebDriver 'Actions' before canning Selenium altogether. I have found I have problems trying to directly evaluate javascript through Selenium WebDriver, but I have also not come across a situation where 'Actions' didn't call the necessary javascript for me.

Maybe post some code on the issues you are having?

EDIT: Also, are you using Selenium IDE or WebDriver? That might be a solution for you in the first place.